# Dynamic columns (order , name , number with limit), in PHP , Laravel, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have an advisory question,
I need to build table with dynamic columns order, name and also give the user the ability to add new columns (6 max).
what is the best way to do these things in **Laravel 8 with MySQL DB**.
My first thought was to add another tables related to this table(one for Order, one for New names, one for new Columns)
but still miss things, I think there is something wrong in the idea.
If any one can help.

Comment: You should use MongoDB.

Comment: You could try JSON columns.